# Error when creating iris model matrix in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a model matrix for the iris set in R.
The code is:

```
Z <- model.matrix(Sepal.Length-Sepal.Width, data=iris)
```

However, it gives me the error:

```
Error in model.matrix(Sepal.Length - Sepal.Width, data = iris) : 
  object 'Sepal.Length' not found.
```

When I just write iris in my console I can however select Sepal.Length by

```
iris$Sepal.Length
```

Maybe you could help to understand what is going wrong ?

Comment: You need `~` and not `-`. Try `model.matrix(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width, data=iris)`